# How to use Array.Find<T>() with multiple parameters?

Tags: c#, arrays

My project has buil in .Net Framework 2.0. So, I could not use **LINQ** in my case.

I am trying to get the result from Array1 and Array2 with left join. both array contains the file names which are returned by using `Directory.GetFiles()` method. Now, I am trying to find the item of Array1 in Array2 by using `Array.Find<T>()` function. I am following this msdn [tutorial.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kkxfxdd(v=vs.80).aspx)

```
foreach (string file in Array1)
{
    String found = Array.Find(Array2, MatchFileName);
    if (found != String.Empty)
    { \\will do my stuff; }
}

private static bool MatchFileName(String s)
{
    string _match = "100-006";
    return ((s.Length > 5) && (s.Substring(0, 7).ToLower() == _match.ToLower()))
}
```

It works fine. But, the problem is that the matching part(`"100-006"`) is not fixed it can be variable as per the item of foreach loop. but, I don't know how to pass another parameter to match with that Array2 element.

I want something like this.

```
foreach (string file in Array1)
{
    String found = Array.Find(Array2, MatchFileName(file));
    if (found != String.Empty)
    { \\will do my stuff; }
}

private static bool MatchFileName(String s, string file)
{
    string _match = file.Substring(0,7);
    return ((s.Length > 5) && (s.Substring(0, 7).ToLower() == _match.ToLower()))
}
```

How do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a class to wrap the argument:

```
public sealed class Finder
{
    private readonly string _match;

    public Finder(string match)
    {
        _match = match.ToLower();
    }

    public bool Match(string s)
    {
        return ((s.Length > 5) && (s.Substring(0, 7).ToLower() == _match));
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var finder = new Finder("100-006");

string found = Array.Find(Array2, finder.Match);
```

Note that this also allows you to optimise away the repeated calls to `_match.ToLower()`.